# What is the importance of watch command in ExtJS

Tags: extjs5, sencha-cmd

I am using ExtJS 5 to create a web application.

I am also using **sencha app build** command to create the production build.

During development I never use **sencha app watch** or **sencha app build** commands. I just do the changes in the application code and in our web server's(tomcat) server.xml file I have given context path of the application code root folder. I just start the tomcat server and load the context by giving the context path.

Now i want to know what is the use of **sencha app watch** command and what are the benefits that developer is going to get using **watch** command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, besides providing a web server, the `watch` command does two main things:

- it rebuilds your `bootstrap.js` file continuously.
- it provides a [Fashion](https://www.sencha.com/blog/how-to-style-apps-with-fashion-in-ext-js-6/) server

If you're trying to change the CSS for your app, by introducing a custom theme, then using Fashion and `sencha app watch` is a massive time saver.

You can also use Tomcat and `sencha app watch` in parallel, by [making your Tomcat instance a proxy](https://twasink.net/2015/07/23/fashionable-extjs-and-web-services/) to the `sencha app watch` version.

Comment: Thanks Robert for the information that you provided.

So if i am going to change the CSS of the app then really this is going to help me reduce the development time.
I have one doubt, does ExtJS 5 support Fashion and if yes then can you please provide me a link from where i can learn and adapt Fashion server in my development process.

Comment: Fashion is not supported in ExtJS5 as far as I know. You can't "adapt the Fashion server" - you need to make your app server proxy to it. A link showing how I did that is above.